# JS - iterating over array and add new numeric for if statement

Tags: javascript, iteration

Lets assume I got some king of array... or for simplicity links.

HTML:

```
<a href'myspecialPath'></a>
<a href'myspecialPath'></a>
<a href'otherPath'></a>
<a href'otherPath'></a>
<a href'myspecialPath'></a>
<a href'myspecialPath'></a>
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var testLength = test.length;

for (i=0; i<testLength; i++){
    if (test.getAttribute('href').indexOf('myspecialPath') !== -1){
        //we list here every link with special patch
        // and I want it to have new numeration, not:
        link[i] have myspecialPath! // 1,2,5,6
        // cause it has gaps if link don't have special path - 1,2,5,6
        // and I want it to have numeric like 1,2,3,4
    }
else{
        link[i] without myspecialPath! // 3,4... and I want 1,2
    }
}
```

I hope everything is clear. I want to number link following from 1 [i+1] to the end without gaps.

**EDIT:**
I did try [y+1] before but thanks to @American Slime the answer is:

```
y = 0;
for (i=0; i<testLength; i++){
        if (test.getAttribute('href').indexOf('myspecialPath') !== -1){
            links:[y ++] have myspecialPath! // 1,2,3,4... and so on, OK - it's working fine!
        }
    }
```

anybody fell free to correct this question/answer to better describe the problem.

Comment: Still vague! Explain more!

Comment: don't use `link[i]`, and instead use `link.push(item)` ?

Comment: create a counter variable, and only increment it when the "if" hits.  Use the counter variable instead of i

Comment: Please elaborate `document.getElementsByTagName('a').indexOf('myspecialPath')`

Comment: oh sorry - document.getElementsByTagName('a').indexOf('myspecialPath') = test.indexOf('myspecialPath')

Comment: You only need to call `getElementsByTagName()` once, not in each iteration through the loop. That function does **not** return an array; it returns a NodeList.

Comment: You can loop over just the links that have `myspecialPath` using this: `var specialLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='myspecialPath']");`

Comment: @Pointy you are correct I want at first use array but link (<a>) NodeList was for me faster and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're asking...

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i <= links.length-1; i++) {

    if (links[i].getAttribute('href') === 'myspecialPath') {

        links[i].setAttribute('href', 'myspecialPath' + count);
        count++;

    };

};
```

Comment: I think it's close, I just want to collect proper iterations but instead of [i] numbers I want my own from 1 to ... (without holes/gaps like 1,2, [missing 3,4 here cause of not all links fulfill if statement]5,6)

Comment: @webmasternewbie It's not clear what you're asking. Can you show what your desired list looks like?

Comment: I did edit my question... simply incrementation... you learn all your life :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want is an array of `myspecialPath` links and another of other links. You can use [**`Array.prototype.push`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which doesn't care about the index like this:

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var testLength = test.length;

var specialLinks = [];
var otherLinks = [];

for (i=0; i<testLength; i++){
    // it should be test[i] not test
    if (test[i].indexOf('myspecialPath') !== -1){
        specialLinks.push(test[i]);
    }
    else{
        otherLinks.push(test[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice, for arrays!